# adopting action filters for both MVC and web Api controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

as you know MVC and web api action filters uses different namespaces for their filters:

in web api:

`public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)`

HttpActionExecutedContext is in `system.web.http.filters`

in MVC:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
```

ActionExecutedContext is in `system.web.mvc`

I want to have one filters for all of my controllers whenever web api or MVC.

so how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

MVC and Web API are different frameworks and where they converge is the hosting part. At this point in time, MVC and Web API can be web-hosted (IIS + ASP.NET pipeline) and hence you can write an IIS module to do what you want.

OWIN middleware could be a better option but unfortunately MVC cannot be OWIN-hosted at this point. However, you can use a stage marker to run an OWIN middleware in ASP.NET pipeline at the stage you want but as far as I can see, `PipelineStage` enum has `PreHandlerExecute` as the last stage. This means you can do something like `OnActionExecuting` but not `OnActionExecuted`.

Comment: thanks for answer, you mean I should have an action filter for MVC controllers and another one for Web API? I goolgled and didn't see any related question and answer. I thought maybe my question is incorrect!

Comment: I'm developing a web app. and it needs a web api. so what is the best approach, having a web app implemented both mvc app and web api, or one web app for mvc and another one for webapi?